# What to do when there's no satisfactory answer?

Tags: discussion

What should we do about questions that get one or more answers, but after 24 hours, none are acceptable as the accepted answer?

Do we just let the question go without an accepted answer?

Comment: We definitely don't want to checkmark answers just for the sake of checkmarking, so yeah, let it go. Just one of those things we have to live with... :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have enough reputation you can start a [bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) on the question and people would be more inclined to answer. Someone else could start a bounty if they find your question interesting.

Other than that, there's not much you can do other than editing your question to clarify it, or commenting on the existing answers and stating why you don't find them acceptable. 24 hours isn't that long, remember that we are still in private beta and there aren't many users, when the public beta begins in 6 days there would be more users and hopefully more answers.

You might find [this discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions) on meta StackOverflow useful.

Answer (score 1):

I've got several questions on StackOverflow that remain uncheckmarked after literally months. Sometimes nobody has a good answer, but the question still theoretically has one. Just don't worry about it - the site will nag you to close it for a bit, but it'll shut up eventually.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's technically encouraged/allowed, but... if you edit a question (even just to change a punctuation mark or add a space) it gets bumped to the top of the homepage on the next refresh (within 60 seconds). You can even time it right to get it at the very top, if you figure out the refresh time and save an edit just before the refresh... Do this around noon and you're sure to get maximal viewing. Do this several times and your question is automatically turned to Community Wiki though (due to lots of edits).

By "refresh" I mean the updating of the homepage. If you refresh the homepage quickly you'll see that the questions on the page don't change but once a minute, precisely every 60 seconds. I assume it limits database traffic or something.

Answer (score 0):

One of the things that's built into the stack exchange software is the [community bot](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) that will occasionally bump old, unanswered questions to the top of the list to get visibility.  So if there is no acceptable answer it's in theory better to leave it un-checked (assuming you come back to the site if somebody eventually does answer it).

Another option is to just do the research yourself, editing the question with new data (which causes it to be bumped) and eventually answer it yourself.  There are badges to encourage this type of behavior.